# Turbolinks are firing twice and causing duplicated script issue

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5, turbolinks

I have upgraded rails version from 4.1.5 to 5.2.4.5. After upgrading turbolinks are firing multiple times and in JS console it's "duplicated script detected" appearing. I have run "**rake assets:clobber**" this command to clear all previous versions but didn't help.

```
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="./jquery.js"></script>
<%= javascript_include_tag "customers", "data-turbolinks-track" => true%>
```

I am using **gem 'turbolinks'** turbolinks (5.2.1) gem for turbolinks. If anyone have any solution, kindly share.

Comment: What do the sprockets directives in `application.js` look like? Is it an issue with the layout? Could you be rendering the script tag twice?

Comment: "//= require turbolinks" add this in js. I don't think so I am rendering it twice as in rails-4.1.5 branch it works fine. This issue only appears in my ROR upgradation branch. @max